# TSQL, select values from large many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables
Publishers and Campaigns, both have similar many-to-many relationships with Countries,Regions,Languages and Categories.

**more info**

Publisher2Categories has publisherID and categoryID which are foreign keys to publisherID in Publishers and categoryID in Categories which are identity columns. On other side i have Campaigns2Categories  with campaignID and categoryID columns which are foreign keys to campaignID in Campaigns and categoryID in Categories which again are identities.
Same goes for Regions, Languages and Countries relationships

**How do I get campaignIDs of Campaigns that have at least one equal to Publisher (I pass to query publisherID) value from regions, countries, language or categories?**

[DB DIAGRAM http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/7264/64255522.png](http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/7264/64255522.png)

[click here for direct link](http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/7264/64255522.png)

thanks

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos, highlighted the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOINING` each individual manytomany table from publishers and campaigns and `UNION`the result should leave you with all campaignid's that have a match between publishers and campains through one of there respective relation tables.

```
SELECT  cc.CampaignID
FROM    dbo.PublisherSites2Countries pc
        INNER JOIN dbo.Campaings2Countries cc ON cc.CountryID = pc.CountryID
UNION SELECT pr.CampaignID
FROM    dbo.PublisherSites2Regions pr
        INNER JOIN dbo.Campaings2Regions cr ON cr.RegionID = pr.RegionID
...
```

Comment: +1. If the CampaignID has to exist in all the four tables, use INTERSECT instead of UNION

Comment: thanks. Finally you've got answer for me. I will check other answer performance versus your and decide which one executes faster with my data.

Thanks again

Comment: *finally you've got answer for me?* That reads like *all other answers you've ever given are worthless*. (for the record, I do assume that's not what you meant ;)

Comment: you are right. This is not what i've meant. I've meant that you asked me many times questions about my question but never gave an answer to any of my questions until now. You questions helped me to organize better questions and get better answers.

Worthless answers are rare in here, mostly they exists because question is not understandable, at least in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to find linked Campaigns and Publishers one join-type at a time, and union the results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT campaignID
  FROM Campaigns2Countries c2cy
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PublisherSites2Countries
                WHERE countryID = c2cy.countryID
                  AND publisherID = :publisherID)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT campaignID
  FROM Campaigns2Categories c2cat
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PublisherSites2Categories
                WHERE categoryID = c2cat.categoryID
                  AND publisherID = :publisherID)
UNION
...
```

Comment: thanks, i will compare performance of this query against my db with other answer to see what performs better